# Here is the question that .i have solve half the output should be 12345 each number on its own line

Tags: python

```
def print_range (start,end):
    n = start
    while n <= end:
        print (n)
print_range(1,5)
```

Output should be 12345

Comment: Please format your code for better readability. please refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0):

you should do this

```
def print_range (start,end):
    n = start
    n_string = str(start)
    while n <= end:
        n_string = n_string+str(n)

    print(n_string)

print_range(1,5)
```